# How do I write unit tests for a NodeJS C++ addon?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, node-gyp

I have written a C++ addon for nodejs. I know C++ and JS, but I'm totally new to writing addons. The addon is component of a larger NodeJS project. The addon builds and runs, so I have no questions about the addon itself.

At this point, I would like to write unit tests for the addon. However, it's not clear what infrastructure or framework supports unit testing for C++ addons. I thought GTest would be a natural choice, but it looks like you have to build your tests with CMake or Bazel. Addons, of course, are built with node-gyp.

With no clear options, I thought to try using node-gyp to build a unit test program, but without any external framework. I started with a stub file `myaddon.test.cpp`, just to see if I could build a simple, standalone binary. The file looks like this:

```
#include "myaddon.mock.h"
#include "myaddon.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cout << "hello, myaddon world" << endl;
}
```

Then I added a target "myaddon.test" to binding.gyp and ran `node-gyp configure build`. The target was built with no errors. But when I run it, it seg faults.

Is there an established way to write unit tests for C++ addons?

Comment: Since a significant part of an add-on is communicating across the C++ / nodejs boundary and handling memory properly, you can only really test that by running a test program within nodejs.  You could conceivably write unit tests in C++ for functions internal to the addon, but that will not be sufficient to test its integration with nodejs.  So, I would think you need to run tests through nodejs.